# What is the mechanism by which paracetamol improves sleep?

Tags: medications, sleep, mechanism-of-action, acetaminophen

45+ old male sleep maintenance issues for couple of years resolved by fixing the basics- blacked out room, avoiding alcohol and coffee having the biggest effect.  Still even if I am able to sleep 8 hours the sleep is not as restorative as I would expect.

Recently I have noted that 500mg paracetamol (tylenol, acetaminophen ) result in truly excellent restorative sleep.

My question is: what could be the mechanism involved?  What hormones are affected by paracetamol that have relevance to sleep?

I would like to modify my diet/lifestyle further to get this type of sleep without the drug.

Normal weight, fighting mild gastrointestinal and dermatological issues that indicate autoimmunity and allergies, on paleo diet since 6 years if that is in any way relevant. I have no pain the drug would help me with.

Comment: Advil btw is a completely different drug from Tylenol/paracetamol.

Comment: I would conclude that you have pain you have got used to and don't think about. It's reasonably common.

Comment: thanks for the note on advil, I have eddited the question

Answer (score 1):

It is rather suggestive of a [nocebo effect](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/what-is-the-nocebo-effect-5451823/?no-ist) since there is no mechanism to explain a connection between sleepiness/weakness and paracetamol use.

According to [eHealthMe](http://www.ehealthme.com/ds/paracetamol/fatigue/),  out of the 1,171 people who reported side effects on paracetamol 64 reported weakness as a side effect, 33 sleepiness as a side effect

Comment: Actually I am not sleepy, the paracetamol causes that I am feeling well rested after sleep

Answer (score -1):

I was at a GP CPD meeting on pain 2 weeks ago and the pain specialist reported tht PCM has weak analgesic effects but is good for stiffness. Many patients have reported better sleep with 2 paracetamol over the years so it may be they are experiencing less micro-wakening when changing position during the night and thus wakening more refreshed. I am concerned about long-term micro damage to liver and use many herbs such including hops and valerian as part of a sleep programm with good results.
Dr Dilis Clare